Does C++23 allow multiple definitions of a namespace-scope non-inline variable in different translation units?
In old versions of C++, such as C++17, the one-definition rule was intuitive at a high-level in that it allowed only one definition of variables

Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement;

But this prohibition has been removed.
Paragraph 14 does include restrictions that "For any definable item D with definitions in multiple translation units, if D is a non-inline non-templated function or variable..." essentially the definitions have to be identical.  But that seems to imply it is indeed possible to have a program like:
// a.cc
int a = 1;

// b.cc
int a = 1;

Did the ODR rule indeed get heavily relaxed for non-inline variables?  If so, why?  If not, what is the new normative language prohibiting such multiple definitions?

"For any definable item D with definitions in multiple translation units, if D is a non-inline non-templated function or variable, or ... the program is ill-formed; ...". It seems to me that this is clear, your a is a non-inline non-templated variable.

Here is a more complete quote from [basic.def.odr] (C++23)

For any definable item D with definitions in multiple translation units,

if D is a non-inline non-templated function or variable, or
if the definitions in different translation units do not satisfy the following requirements,

the program is ill-formed;

This rule has not changed.
For any definition in multiple translation units:

The first bullet is telling you non-inline non-templated definitions are an ODR violation

That makes your code example an ODR violation in C++23.

The second bullet is telling you that inline or templated definitions can still be ODR violations if, for example, they aren't the same code.


Sorry, I accidentally had the wrong link and was linking to C++17 in both places.  I've fixed my question to link properly to C+23.

And the thing I'm taking issue with is that my example satisfies the following requirements, so would seem to be legal.

"the following requirements" are only for inline symbols and templates. First bullet (your code) or second bullet (requirements fail) makes it an ODR violation

Yes, I accepted your answer, thanks.  The key is that the two bullets are joined by or, so it's illegal regardless of the rest.  So now I'm confused about the common pre-C++17 practice of having constexpr variables in header files, and then using those headers in C++23 programs.  But that will have to be the topic of another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78983732/are-multiple-identical-non-inline-constexpr-variable-definitions-allowed-in-diff
