Are multiple identical non-inline constexpr variable definitions allowed in different translation units in C++23?
C++23 says that constexpr functions and static data members are implicitly inline, but it does not say the same for namespace-scope constexpr variables.  It also says that: "For any definable item D with definitions in multiple translation units, if D is a non-inline non-templated function or variable... the program is ill-formed."
Since inline variables were only introduced in C++17, there are a lot of legacy header files with non-inline constexpr variables.  Why is it not illegal for multiple translation units to contain definitions of the same constexpr variable, as in:
// include.h
constexpr int my_constant = 1;


Have you considered that it may be forbidden but not a detectable violation ("No Diagnostic Required")?

Note of course that it's ok to be at namespace scope in the anonymous namespace, and that's how header files should have been defining constants all along (assuming no odr-use, or at least none that depends on object identity).

Your example does not define the same variable more than once; it defines a separate variable with internal linkage in each TU where include.h is #included ([basic.link]/8).
[dcl.constexpr]/6:

A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const.

[basic.link]/3.2:

The name of an entity that belongs to a namespace scope has internal linkage if it is the name of

a non-template variable of non-volatile const-qualified type



It may be relevant to OP's understanding that there second quote continues with ", unless [...], or it is inline, or [...]". inline typically will give the constant variable external linkage again.

Aha.  So constexpr implies const, and const variables have internal linkage by default.  That makes sense.
